# partial results from a long-running SELECT query?

Tags: sql, mysql, database, select

We are issuing some long running queries on a mysql database. (The context is offline data analysis, not an application.) How we will proceed in research terms depends on the results we obtain along the way. It would be useful for us to be able to view (partial) results **as they are generated** by a SELECT statement -- before the query completes.

Is this possible? Or are we stuck with waiting until the query completes (which given the size of the dataset can take a couple of hours) to view results which were generated in the very first seconds it ran?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: why don't you split the result up using LIMIT?

Comment: @Moak: thank you for the idea! But we tried this and unfortunately it does not work. Appending "LIMIT 0, one_fifth_of_the_returned_records" to a query runs for as a long as the same query without the LIMIT. It does *not* produce the first fifth of the results in a shorter period of time.

Comment: It would of course be much easier to avoid "psyching answers" here if you could actually post one of the long-running queries in its full form.

Comment: welcome in 2018, nothing has changed, but what I can tell you is that you could try introducing indexes to your queries, so `WHERE` + `LIMIT` would work faster

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to hazard a guess that you have `ORDER BY` or `GROUP BY` as part of your query.

Most database engines I've used all starts streaming data back to the client as soon as it can, even if it hasn't fetched them all internally yet. However, once you throw `GROUP BY` or `ORDER BY` into the mix, the engine doesn't know what the first row will look like until it has produced the entire data set server-side, which is why you're left waiting for a long time.

Comment: GROUP BY might be okay, if there are no aggregate functions (if the GROUP BY is functionally just a DISTINCT)

Answer (score 5):

The simplest thing to try is to use unbuffered queries. Then mysql will start delivering data as soon as it can, rather than when it has everything ready (and buffered). Depending on your query, this may not help.

To really speed things up, you need to break up your query. Not just using LIMIT, that's not going to save you much time depending on your query. For example, if you have an ORDER BY, pretty much the whole result set will have to be calculated first. You would only save the time it would take to deliver less data across the network.

Split up your queries by doing a filter. If you have a field that is indexed that you can do range searches on (i.e. auto increment), then break up your query into multiple queries using that field. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM db WHERE field1 BETWEEN 1 AND 10000;
SELECT * FROM db WHERE field1 BETWEEN 10000 AND 20000;
...
```

Then you can combine the results afterward. Many times multiple queries like this will complete faster than the equivalent single query. But if you do have an ORDER BY or GROUP BY, this may not be possible. 
But you could still try breaking it up into smaller queries, join them with a UNION and select on the UNION with your grouping and order by. Believe or not, this can still be much quicker than the equivalent single query. You just have to get the individual queries processing a small enough data set to make them quick.

```
SELECT field1, SUM(field3) field3, SUM(item_count) item_count FROM 
(
SELECT field1, SUM(field3) field3, COUNT(item) item_count FROM db WHERE field1 BETWEEN 1 AND 10000 GROUP BY field1
UNION
SELECT field1, SUM(field3) field3, COUNT(item) item_count FROM db WHERE field1 BETWEEN 10000 AND 20000 GROUP BY field1
UNION
...
) AS sub_queries GROUP BY field1
```

Divide and conquer. Using this technique I've sometimes reduced query times from an hour down to a minute or two.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for adding this as a new answer, but the "add comment" button still doesn't show :

@Lasse,

The question sounded to me like the OP was interested in "intermediately knowing about the current value of, say, a running sum that is being computed".

That cannot be done, period.

If the OP's question was rather in the direction of what you indicate, which is all about getting "early subsets of the full result set", then my suggestion would of course be to resort to techniques of quota queries.  You know, "OPTIMIZE FOR 20 ROWS" and that sort of stuff.

Comment: I agree, if the final result is depending on everything being materialized first, there is simply no way of knowing this. It's like trying to give you a percentage of how many people you have counted in the census so far, without knowing how many people exists until you've actually counted them all.

Comment: You get the ability to add comments when you have 50 reputation, but perhaps you already knew that. Welcome to Stack Overflow in any case :)

Comment: I added this comment while my rep score was at 11 :-)

Answer (score 0):

Returning intermediate results while the "full" query" is still in progress, is against the spirit of how SQL, and even the relational model, was originally conceived.

The RM, and even SQL, were conveived to return only full-and-final results once those are "fully-and-finally" computed.

If you want to get statistically reliable approximations of the final result that are based on a subset of the population, you HAVE TO RESORT to techniques of statistics and extrapolation.

Comment: It is, however, entirely normal for most database engines to start streaming the results back to the client as soon as it can. Some result sets can take up a large portion of the server memory, or possibly even disk if it is really large, and if the server doesn't have a real reason to produce the entire dataset server-side first, it will usually start transmitting row batches as soon as it can, to avoid having to cache it all. However, sorting and grouping requires a full production server-side before it can begin streaming.