# How can I select some amount of rows, like "get as many rows as possible in 5 seconds"?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

The aim is: getting the highest number of rows and not getting more rows than rows loaded, after 5 seconds. The aim is not creating a timeout.

after months, I thought maybe this would work and it didn't:

```
declare @d1 datetime2(7); set @d1=getdate();
select c1,c2 from t1 where (datediff(ss,@d1,getdate())<5)
```

Comment: eeee... still very blur, can you putting some sample data / output ?

Comment: What host programming language will you use to query mysql?

Comment: is this a duplicate? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163416/partial-results-from-a-long-running-select-query

Comment: To "get as many rows as possible" you will have to profile the actual query. Until you post the actual query you're using, we will only be guessing the length of the emperor's nose.

Comment: The question seems clear enough, what isn't clear is why would you want to retrieve this information?  Are you trying to highlight periods of the day when your database runs more slowly than others?

Answer (score 27):

Although the trend in recent years for relational databases has moved more and more toward cost-based query optimization, there is no RDBMS I am aware of that inherently supports designating a maximum cost (in time or I/O) for a query.

The idea of "just let it time out and use the records collected so far" is a flawed solution. The flaw lies in the fact that a complex query may spend the first 5 seconds performing a hash on a subtree of the query plan, to generate data that will be used by a later part of the plan. So after 5 seconds, you may still have no records.

To get the *most records possible* in 5 seconds, you would need a query that had a known estimated execution plan, which could then be used to estimate the optimal number of records to request in order to make the query run for as close to 5 seconds as possible. In other words, knowing that the query optimizer estimates it can process 875 records per second, you could request 4,375 records. The query might run a bit longer than 5 seconds sometimes, but over time your average execution should fall close to 5 seconds.

So...how to make this happen?

In your particular situation, it's not feasible. The catch is "known estimated execution plan". To make this work reliably, you'd need a stored procedure with a known execution plan, not an ad-hoc query. Since you can't create stored procedures in your environment, that's a non-starter.  For others who want to explore that solution, though, [here's an academic paper by a team who implemented this concept in Oracle.](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.102.3249)  I haven't read the full paper, but based on the abstract it sounds like their work could be translated to any RDBMS that has cost-based optimization (e.g. MS SQL, MySQL, etc.)

**OK, So what can YOU do in your situation?**

If you can't do it the "right" way, solve it with a hack.

My suggestion: keep your own "estimated cost" statistics.

Do some testing in advance and estimate how many rows you can typically get back in 4 seconds.  Let's say that number is 18,000.

So you LIMIT your query to 18,000 rows. But you also track the execution time every time you run it and keep a moving average of, say, the last 50 executions. If that average is less than 4.5s, add 1% to the query size and reset the moving average. So now your app is requesting 18,180 rows every time.  After 50 iterations, if the moving average is under 4.5s, add 1% again.

And if your moving average ever exceeds 4.75s, subtract 1%.

Over time, this method should converge to an optimized N-rows solution for your particular query/environment/etc. And should adjust (slowly but steadily) when conditions change (e.g. high-concurrency vs low-concurrency)

**Just one -- scratch that, two -- more things...**

1. As a DBA, I have to say...it should be exceedingly rare for any query to take more than 5 seconds. In particular, if it's a query that runs frequently and is used by the front end application, then it absolutely *should not* ever run for 5 seconds. If you really do have a user-facing query that can't complete in 5 seconds, that's a sign that the database design needs improvement.
2. **Jonathan VM's Law Of The Greenbar Report** I used to work for a company that still used a mainframe application that spit out reams of greenbar dot-matrix-printed reports every day. Most of these were ignored, and of the few that were used, most were never read beyond the first page. A report might have thousands of rows sorted by descending account age...and all that user needed was to see the 10 most aged. My law is this: *The number of use cases that actually require seeing a vast number of rows is infinitesimally small.* Think - really think - about the use case for your query, and whether having lots and lots of records is really what that user needs.

Answer (score 5):

Your while loop idea won't solve the problem entirely. It is possible that the very first iteration through the loop could take longer than 5 seconds. Plus, it will likely result in retrieving far fewer rows in the allotted time than if you tried to do it with just a single query.

Personally, I wouldn't try to solve this exact problem. Instead, I would do some testing, and through trial and error identify a number of records that I am confident will load in under five seconds. Then, I would just place a LIMIT on the loading query.

Next, depending on the requirements I would either set a timeout on the DB call of five seconds or just live with the chance that some calls will exceed the time restriction.

Lastly, consider that on most modern hardware for most queries, you can return a very large number of records within five seconds. It's hard to imagine returning all of that data to the UI and still have it be usable, if that is your intention.

-Jason

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried this, but if a script is running this query you could try running an unbuffered query (in php, this would be something like mysql_unbuffered_query())... you could then store these into an array while the query is running. You could then set the mysql query timeout to five minutes. When the query is killed, if you've set your while() loop to check for a timeout response it can then terminate the loop and you'll have an array with all of the records returned in 5 minutes. Again, I'm not sure this would work, but I'd be interested to see if it would accomplish what you're looking to do.

Answer (score 0):

You could approach this problem like this, but I doubt that this logic is really what I'd recommend for real world use.

You have a 10s interval, you try one query, it gets you the row in 0.1s. That would imply you could get at least 99 similar queries still in the remaining 9.9s.
However, getting 99 queries at once should proove faster than getting them one-by-one (which your initial calculation would suggest). So you get the 99 queries and check the time again.

Let's say the operation performed 1.5 times as fast as the single query, because getting more queries at once is more efficient, leaving you with 100rows at a time of 7.5s. You calculate that by average you have so far gotten 100rows per 7.5s, calculate a new amount of possible queries for the rest of the time and query again, and so on. You would, however, need to set a threshold limit for this loop, let's say something like: Don't get any new queries any more after 9.9s.

This solution obviously is neither the most smooth nor something I'd really use, but maybe it serves to solve the OP's problem.
Also, jmacinnes already pointed out: "It is possible that the very first iteration through the loop could take longer than 10[5] seconds."

I'd certainly be interested myself, if someone can come up with a proper solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

To get data from the table you should do two things:

1. execute a query (SELECT something FROM table)
2. fill the table or **read data**

You are asking about second one. I'm not that familiar with php, but I think it does not matter. We use fetching to get first records quickly and show them to the user, then fetch records as needed. In ADO.NET you could use IDataReader to get records one by one, in php I think you could use similar methods, for example - [mysqli_fetch_row](http://ua.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php) in mysqli extension or [mysql_fetch_row](http://ua.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php) in mysql extension. In this case you could stop reading data at any moment.