# partial results from a long-running SELECT query? SQL-Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

This question exists for MySQL [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163416/partial-results-from-a-long-running-select-query)

I would like to know it for SQL-Server

Problem: How to optimize a query for Partial result set to be displayed quickly irrespective of its total running time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`OPTION (FAST N)`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx)

Where `N` is the number of rows to optimise for.

For low values of `N` this will encourage a query plan that uses non blocking operators  (e.g nested loops joins) that can return the first rows quickly.

Comment: Thanks @Martin this is very helpful. Unfortunately, due to the design of my application, i am unable to use OPTION. Can you please tell me some best practices for writing a query under which i can achieve this.

Comment: Can you use [plan guides](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190417.aspx)? These allow you to apply a hint without altering the query sent by the application. Otherwise I'm not sure what type of answer you are looking for. `OPTION (FAST N)` pretty much does exactly what you need. What kind of constraint means you can't use it? What changes *can* you make to the query?